# I am confused how to support async / await with C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function which generates triangles from a list of points. I want to add an async function as an option encase there is a high amount of triangles to generate.

I am struggling to understand how to use the async/await syntax.

I currently get the error `cannot await void`

This is my setup:

```
public static async Task TriangulateAsync(IReadOnlyList<Point> verts, List<Triangle> triangles)
{
    await Triangulate(verts, triangles);
}
public static void Triangulate(in IReadOnlyList<Point> verts, in List<Triangle> triangles)
{
   // regular triangulation logic
}
```

The idea here is i now have the choice between an async or a synchronous triangulation. But this does not work. What is the correct way to set this up?

Comment: Change Triangulate from void to Task. However we do not know the underlying code of Triangulate so it is difficult to understand why you need async/await to begin with. If you await an async Task method, the thread becomes blocked and waits for the result of the awaited Task. If you assign an async Task to _ and do not await it, it will run without blocking the thread and not wait for the result of the Task.

Answer (score -2):

At first, you can `await` only `Task` or function, that returns it. There should be some API, which generates `Task`. You can get it from some I/O API (as DB/network request, filesystem call, etc.) or delegate a workload to another thread and recieve `Task` to control it as a result.

Why do async function needed here? Let's imagine, that `Triangulate` is a heavy cpu-bound task. So, we can perform it on another thread by [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-run(system-action)):

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static async Task TriangulateAsync(IReadOnlyList<Point> verts, List<Triangle> triangles)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => Triangulate(verts, triangles)); // Run on another thread
}
```

or if `await` is a single and last, it (`async`/`await`) can be omitted:

```cs
public static Task TriangulateAsync(IReadOnlyList<Point> verts, List<Triangle> triangles)
{
    return Task.Run(() => Triangulate(verts, triangles));
}
```

P.S. Keep in mind that lots of calls (hundreds) `TriangulateAsync` can be heavy and expensive by itself. And sharing some state (objects) between tasks/threads - it's a [bad idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) generally.